# how to tag a docker image using an environment variable

Tags: bash, docker, github, github-actions

i've discovered that instead of unzipping a .tar.gz file, i am better off loading it:

```
  - name: Load image 
    run: docker load -i pga.tar.gz
```

for some reason, it does not come with a name - so i need to extract the id...the only way i've seen that is possible:

```
  - name: Get image id
    run: imageid=$(docker images --format="{{.ID}}" | head -n 1); echo "$imageid"
```

what i get for that part looks good:

```
Run imageid=$(docker images --format="{{.ID}}" | head -n 1); echo "$imageid"
fc6e040841a1
```

but when i try to tag....

```
 - name: Tag image 
    run:
      docker tag $imageid
      registry.digitalocean.com/abda-containers/abd_db:${{github.event.inputs.version }}
```

it gives me:

```
Run docker tag $imageid registry.digitalocean.com/abda-containers/abd_db:kk
  docker tag $imageid registry.digitalocean.com/abda-containers/abd_db:kk
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
"docker tag" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker tag --help'.

Usage:  docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]

Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

not sure what to do..

Comment: Usually you'd `docker pull` the image from a registry; I'd only use `docker save` and `docker load` in environments where you _can't_ run a registry (maybe it's on a physically isolated network).  Is there a specific workflow that leads you to have a tar file?

Comment: In addition to this being a concerning design (passing a tgz instead of using a registry), it appears you're setting the imageid in one run step, and trying to use it in a separate run step, which is likely running from a different shell command without the variable defined.

Comment: @DavidMaze i've just discovered that wsl2 changes the ip address on every reboot...so i want to get out of there...

Comment: @BMitch that would explain alot...the thing is, i've been able to push it direct from wsl2 to the registry...i but i would like to know how to do this incase i work on something in wsl2 and decide to push that into there using githubactions since my vscode is connected to it